# How to improve Mongo document retrieval performance

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, performance, crud

I am retrieving documents from a Mongo database and copying them to internal storage. I'm finding it takes more than a few seconds to retrieve and store a hundred of these documents. Is there anything I can do to improve the performance? Some of collections have more than 1000 documents. Here's what I have (written in vb.net)

```
' get the documents from collection "reqitems" and put them in "collection"
Dim collection As IFindFluent(Of BsonDocument, BsonDocument) = _
                            reqitems.Find(Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Empty)
ReDim model.ReqItems(TotalCollection.ToList.Count)  ' storage for the processed documents
For Each item As BsonDocument In TotalCollection.ToList()  
  ' note: given a string a=x, "GetRHS" returns x 
  Dim parentuid As String = GetRHS(item.GetElement("parentuid").ToString)  
  Dim nodename As String = GetRHS(item.GetElement("nodename").ToString) 
  ' .... about a dozen of these elements
  ' .... process the elements and copy them to locations in model.ReqItems
next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding indices didn't really help. What slows it down is accessing the elements in the document one at a time (GetRHS in the posted code). So, as a fix, I converted the document to a string, then parse the string for keyword-value pair. Hopefully, what I found might be able to help someone with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can add indexes to your collection if you haven't done so. Please refer to : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Also, I would suggest to run the particular Mongodb query with executions stats. ex: `db.mycollection.find().explain("executionStats");` which will give you more stats regarding the performance of the query. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#executionstats